# untangling heroku and git between a fork, staging and production

Tags: git, heroku

I am overwhelmed at this point and need some help, I am helping out myself :)

There's a master repo at github. I have been urged to fork it to work on some issues. So my fork is local.

Now, there's a staging and a production environment on heroku - they are already set up and running.

What's best to manage this environment with git?
I need to work locally, push changes to both heroku envs, and occasionally issue a pull request upstream. My focus right now is to push on heroku.

I did:

```
git remote add production git@heroku.com:heroku_funny_production_name.git
git remote add test git@heroku.com:heroku_funny_test_name.git
```

Can I now just do `git push test master` and `git push production master`?

And, **really important**, if that's correct, before doing that, I'd like to compare the current state of say 'test' with my local master, before pushing, how do I do this?